# Link Error in Visual Studio 2017 with restbed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, restbed

I followed resthub github for building the library

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DBUILD_SSL=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" ..
msbuild INSTALL.vcxproj
```

It successfully created distibution folder. I added those in my sample restbed project as shown below
[image]

[image]

But I am getting the link error as shown below when building[image: i]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's better to copy the actual text of the error messages from the Output tab instead of a picture of the errors list.

Comment: Looks like you added the library directories to the linker setting but not a library to the linker->input->additional dependencies so unless the library has a `#pragma comment(lib,libname.lib)` in a header you are not linking to the required library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three steps to add a lib:

`Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories`

`Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`

`Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`

Also, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=vs-2019) about `lnk2019`.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to add Input. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: came across to same problem, care to share what excat lib solved the above error ?
it seems it's not recognizing the std::wstring. and not complaining about any swagger generated lib files...